# How to separately insert several lines from textBox to sqlite database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite

I am learning SQL, so I decided to write a simple Windows Forms app in C# to put data into a database.

I have a `Students` table with

- `studentID` (integer)
- `name` (varchar(250))
- `contractPrice` (integer)
- `department` (integer)
  columns

My code works if there is 1 line of input in every textBox and here is my question: how can I reorganize my code, so it accepts several lines separated by comma and separately insert that data into the database with their own unique ids?

I tried using an array, but I don't get how to send elements of the array to the database.

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DB = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DB.db; Version=3");
    DB.Open();
}

private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (idtb.Text != "" && nametb.Text != "" && 
        contractPricetb.Text != "" && departmenttb.Text != "") 
    { 
        SQLiteCommand CMD = DB.CreateCommand();
        CMD.CommandText = "insert into Students (StudentID, FullName, ContractPrice, Department) " +
                          "values (@studentid, @fullname, @contractprice, @department)";

        CMD.Parameters.Add("@studentid", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = idtb.Text;
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@fullname", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = nametb.Text;
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@contractprice", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = fullPaymenttb.Text;
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@department", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = studyProgramtb.Text;

        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to be able to enter `1,2` into the ID textbox, `Jane,Bob` into the name textbox, `12,14` into the cost textbox and `7,3` into the department textbox, and have your code insert two rows into the table with the values `1,Jane,12,7` and `2,Bob,14,3`? Feels like an odd user experience to me, which makes me think that I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @sbridewell that's exactly what I want! I just imagined the situation when a user has many students and just copy-pastes from some other sources, so it would take too much time to insert students one by one

Comment: You state that… _”I just imagined the situation when a user has many students and just copy-pastes from some other sources, so it would take too much time to insert students one by one”_ … ? … Even in that situation, the user would still have to copy-paste from whatever source you have into the individual text boxes one by one. What is this “other source” you imagine? Is it a file or DB table? And is there some reason your code does not directly “read” the data from the data source the user is copy-pasting from?

Comment: @JohnG user copy-pastes `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` into ID textbox, `Helen, John, Michel, Stacy, Veronica` into name tb and etc. into every textbox one by one. Then my code inserts 5 rows with corresponding values. And by other source I mean a file. Reason for not directly 'reading' is that the user might have info in different sources or source file might have too much extra information. Moreover, I think it will be good to know how to use array with sql

Comment: Well… I would think a grid would work better from a user perspective and it will make things easier for you. However, if you want to get the data as you describe, then you will have to obviously “Split” each “ID” string, “Name” string etc. on a comma to separate the individual items in each text box. Then you could loop through those collections and write the data to the DB.

Comment: Also, this is putting a lot of faith in the user getting it right and more code for you to write to “make sure” they did get it right. I can only assume that the USERS are requesting this? Again, I would think a grid would work better for you and the user.